# Splitting List into List of List

Tags: scala, list, time, split, functional-programming

How can I convert:

```
List(1,1,1,1,4,2,2,2,2)
```

into:

```
List(List(1,1,1,1), List(2,2,2,2))
```

Thought this would be the easiest way to show what I'm looking for. I am having a hard time trying to find the most functional way to do this with a large list that needs to be separated at a specific element. This element does not show up in the new list of lists. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to support multiple instances of that separator, you can use `foldRight` with some list "gymnastics":

```
// more complex example: separator (4) appears multiple times
val l = List(1,1,1,1,4,2,2,2,2,4,5,6,4)

val separator = 4

val result = l.foldRight(List[List[Int]]()) {
  case (`separator`, res) => List(Nil) ++ res
  case (v, head :: tail) => List(v :: head) ++ tail
  case (v, Nil) => List(List(v))
}

// result: List(List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(2, 2, 2, 2), List(5, 6))
```

Comment: very attractive way of writing code for getting list of lists out of a list meeting the requirement.!

Answer (score 2):

Given a list and a delimiter, in order to split the list in 2:

```
val list = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2)
val delimiter = 4
```

- you could use a combination of [`List.indexOf`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#indexOf(elem:A):Int), [`List.take`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#take(n:Int):List[A]) and [`List.drop`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#drop(n:Int):List[A]):

  ```
  val splitIdx = list.indexOf(delimiter)
  List(list.take(splitIdx), list.drop(splitIdx + 1))
  ```
- you could use [`List.span`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#span(p:A=%3EBoolean):(List[A],List[A])) which splits the list into a tuple given a predicate:

  ```
  list.span(_ != delimiter) match { case (l1, l2) => List(l1, l2.tail) }
  ```

in order to produce:

```
List(List(1, 1, 1, 1), List(2, 2, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the cleanest way to do this

```
val (l, _ :: r) = list.span( _ != 4)
```

The `span` function splits the list at the first value not matching the condition, and the de-structuring on the left-hand side removes the matching value from the second list.

This will fail if there is no matching value.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val l = List(1,1,1,1,4,2,2,2,2)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2)

scala> l.splitAt(l.indexOf(4))
res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 1, 1, 1),List(4, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(list: List[Int], separator: Int): List[List[Int]] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def rec(acc: List[List[Int]], listTemp: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    if (listTemp.isEmpty) acc 
    else {
      val (l, _ :: r) = listTemp.span(_ != separator)
      rec(acc ++ List(l), r)
    }
  }

  rec(List(), list)
}
```